# How to create docker overlay network?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

My efforts to create overlay network are in vain.

```
docker network create --driver overlay new_network
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

Docker-machine list

```
 docker-machine ls
NAME              ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
dev               -        virtualbox   Stopped                                       Unknown    
swarm-manager-1   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.103:2376           v18.09.5
```

If I try

```
docker $(docker-machine config swarm-manager-1) swarm init --advertise-addr $(docker-machine ip swarm-manager-1)
```

it says

```
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

How to create overlay network?
How to inspect the swarm?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT
This works

```
docker $(docker-machine config swarm-manager-1) network create --driver overlay new_network
ym9wva4e8ejqji9cn61tf14kv
```

Anyway overlay network is not visible

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                                      DRIVER              SCOPE
ab450fe43ca5        bridge                                    bridge              local
14dbdf7dc1d9        chapter11_kong-net                        bridge              local
0a76583939bc        dockerapp_default                         bridge              local
b2c31f5e97c7        host                                      host                local
569e2a86568b        microservices-docker-go-mongodb_default   bridge              local
68174733413c        miki_default                              bridge              local
fbafcb186ac9        none
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried: docker $(docker-machine config swarm-manager-1) network create --driver overlay new_network

Comment: It works,you can answer,thanks.

Comment: You create the network in a swarm context but then you look for it in your local context. This is why you can't see it. The easiest thing to do it to set your current terminal session for the right context: run `docker-machine env swarm-manager-1` and then run the last command mentioned in the output. Then whatever docker command you run it will be against your swarm context.

Comment: Works perfect with env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have different configurations on your machine. You have to run the `docker network` command in the same context as the `docker swarm` command from your example:

```
docker $(docker-machine config swarm-manager-1) network create --driver overlay new_network
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't see it yet but I'll check later after it's been reviewed.

Comment: @RichardRublev I replied. We can chat about it if it still doesn't work.